# Regex taking too long in python

Tags: python, regex

I have used regex101 to test my regex and it works fine.What i am trying to is to detect these patterns

1. section 1.2 random 2
2. 1.2 random 2
3. 1.2. random 2
4. random 2
5. random 2.

But its just random it shouldn't match if the string is like that

1. random

My regex is this.

```
  m = re.match(r"^(((section)\s*|(\d+\.)|\d+|(\d+\.\d+)|[a-zA-z\s]|[a-zA-z\.\s])+((\d+\.$)|\d+$|(\d+\.\d+$)))","random random random random random",flags = re.I)
```

If i give in a long string it gets stuck.Any ideas?

Comment: The regex is flagged with "catastrophic backtracking" on regex101, which basically is due to too many groups and stuff. Now, if you just care about the string not being a plain "random" you could just get away by searching for the string 'random' with the condition it not to be in the position zero. Would this be enough: `if my_string.find('random') != 0` ?

Comment: Actually, this wouldn't help for your case #4,#5: then you could search for 'random' and make sure it's not an exact string or so, through length for example. In other words, you may not need to get to use regex in the first place.

Comment: Run-time result is really suprising. Nothing _that criminal_ can be noticed from quick glance on this regex indeed..
Yet something should be there

Comment: @sal This is just an example actually,random can be any string

Comment: reducing this RegEx of some parts (these (\d+\.)|\d+|(\d+\.\d+) can end with tons of lookups) to isolate the troubling piece should help I believe

Comment: Try this regex: `r'(?:section)*\s*(?:[0-9.])*\s*random\s+(?:[0-9.])*'`

Comment: @agg3l the problem for the shown case lies within the `([a-zA-z\s]|[a-zA-z\.\s])+`. Both alternatives are valid for the given input, while it doesn't match the whole pattern - so they are grouped up in every possible combination before the match finally fails.

Comment: @SebastianProske Good point. I've just made a _very quick_ look on the regex itself %(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some simplification, this regular expression meets the requirements stated above and reproduced in the test cases below.

```
import re

regex = r'(?:section)*\s*(?:[0-9.])*\s*random\s+(?!random)(?:[0-9.])*'

strings = [
   "random random random random random",
   "section 1.2 random 2",
   "1.2 random 2",
   "1.2. random 2",
   "random 2",
   "random 2.",
   "random",
]

for string in strings:
    m = re.match(regex, string, flags = re.I)
    if m:
        print "match on", string
    else:
        print "non match on", string
```

which gives an output of:

```
non match on random random random random random
match on section 1.2 random 2
match on 1.2 random 2
match on 1.2. random 2
match on random 2
match on random 2.
non match on random
```

See it in action at: https://eval.in/661183